# Is it possible to change url displayed in address bar for my firebase web?

Tags: firebase

I bought a domain called xxx.net from godaddy.

When I type this address in browser, it gives the firebase page.

However, the url displayed in the address bar automatically changes to xxx.firebaseapp.com .

I want to change the url displayed to be xxx.net.

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Here is my firebase json.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If I google for "firebase custom domain" I instantly come across many instructional articles. Have you followed any of those? If so, what problems are you having?

Comment: Those instructions do not change what url to displayed in the address bar of the browser.

Comment: They only sync the goDaddy server with firebase server.

Comment: "Those instructions" - which instructions? Firebase's documentation has different instructions for different parts of using a custom domain name. Please be more specific. Also, "sync the GoDaddy server with the firebase server" is an inaccurate and imprecise description about how DNS works and Firebase's support for custom domains.

Comment: Those are **not** instructions from the official Firebase documentation - and that page only covers setting up DNS records, not reconfiguring your Firebase application. Please post your `firebase.json` file.

Comment: I am not asking how to connect firebase with "a custom domain".  I want to the url displayed in the address bar to be my custom domain as well.

Comment: That's literally what you're asking to do.

Comment: "Those instructions do not change what url to displayed in the address bar of the browser." That's actually precisely what the Firebase instructions do. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've set up a redirect from your custom domain at GoDaddy to the default domain that Firebase created for you.

If you follow the Firebase instructions on [connecting a custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain), you will add `A` records to your DNS (at GoDaddy), which serve the exact same content as you currently see, but then directly when you type in your own domain name, instead of with a redirection.

If you're having a hard time making this work, edit your question to show how you've set up your DNS zone at GoDaddy, and how you configured the domain in the Firebase Hosting console. The `firebase.json` file has no setting that are relevant to the custom domain.

Comment: Thank you! That’s indeed the problem I had... I just disabled redirect and everything works! :)